# Handling similar exceptions for multiple variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, valueerror, try-except

How do I handle the exceptions in such a way that I get a separate comment for the same exception with two different variables.

```
    try:
        global a
        a = int(num)
    except ValueError:
        print(num, "is not a number. Please try again...")
    try:
        global b
        b= int(denom)
        return (Fraction(a, b))
    except ValueError:
        print(denom, "is not a number. Please try again...")
```

How do I add both the variables in the same try block but have two different exception blocks as I have two print statements. The issue with the above code is that if I input a string instead of number for variable "a", the system prints the statement but throws the below error too:

NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Also, where do I add the return function?

Comment: What do you want to do if `int(num)` raises an exception? Surely you don't want to simply log the error and continue to try to use `a` as an argument to `Fraction`? As a general rule, keep the code in the `try` block as small as possible. If it can't raise the exception you expect to handle, move it outside the `try` block.

Comment: This is a bit heuristic, but: `import re; print(re.search("10: '(.*)'$",str(e)).group(1), "is not a number. Please try again...")`

Comment: Ok so suppose I input "hello" for numerator and 9 for denominator, so it should throw the exception and exit the code, but it throws the above error after throwing the exception.

Comment: try:
            global a
            a = int(num)
            b = int(denom)
            return (Fraction(a, b))
        except ValueError:
            print(num, "is not a number. Please try again...")
        except ValueError:
            print(denom, "is not a number. Please try again...")

So the above code works fine if numerator is "hello" and denominator is 6, but if I interchange them it does not work and tells me 6 is not a number, something needs to be changed here.

Comment: So I am taking two numbers (numerator and denominator) from the user, I want to print "numerator inserted is not a number" if the numerator is not a number or print "denominator inserted is not a number" if the denominator is not a number, but both are value errors so I can't have separate except blocks. Also only if both are valid numbers I can call the fraction function, so dont know how to call it if one of them is wrong

Comment: And **what** do you want to do once you've communicated to the user one of them is wrong? Because after you just print an error message in the except block, you neither terminate the script, nor take care of the error.

Comment: After the error message I want to print the statement again saying enter the numerator, so the same input statement

Answer (score 0):

this will help you handle your exception

```
def Fraction(a,b):
    try:
        assert type(a) ==int, "is not a number. Please try again..."
        assert type(b)==int, "is not a number. Please try again..."
        .........
    except AssertionError as msg:
            print(msg)
```